# What else could I try to avoid catastrophic forgetting in my implementation of Semi-Gradient SARSA?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, pytorch, function-approximation, sarsa

I was trying to implement the semi-gradient SARSA algorithm (see p.244 Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction) using PyTorch:

```
class SemiGradientSARSA(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, env, hidden_dim, lr, epsilon) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.state_space = env.observation_space.shape[0]
        self.action_space = env.action_space.n
        self.goal_position = 0.5 # used for customizing the reward function in MountainCar
        self.starting_position = -0.5 # used for customizing the reward function in MountainCar
        self.epsilon = epsilon
        self.q_net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.state_space, hidden_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(hidden_dim, 2*hidden_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(2*hidden_dim, self.action_space)
        )
        self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.q_net.parameters(), lr=lr)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.from_numpy(x)
        return self.q_net(x)

    def act(self, state):
        # epsilon greedy policy
        p = random.random()
        if p < self.epsilon:
            action = np.random.randint(0, self.action_space)
        else:
            q_values = self(state).detach().numpy()
            action = np.argmax(q_values)
        return action
    
    def train(self, n_episodes):
        for i in range(n_episodes):
            print(f'episode {i}')
            done = False
            trunc = False
            state, info = env.reset()
            action = env.action_space.sample()
            while not done and not trunc:
                next_state, reward, done, trunc, info = env.step(action)
                position, vel = state
                # reward for being further away from the starting position
                if not done:
                    reward = -0.1 * np.abs(position - self.starting_position)
                else:
                    reward = 10
                if done:
                    pred = self(state)[action]
                    loss = 0.5 * (reward - pred)**2
                else:
                    next_action = self.act(next_state)
                    loss = 0.5 * ((reward + 0.99 * self(next_state)[next_action]).detach() - self(state)[action])**2
                loss.backward()
                torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(self.q_net.parameters(), max_norm=1.0, norm_type=2)
                self.optimizer.step()
                self.optimizer.zero_grad()
                action = next_action
                state = next_state

agent = SemiGradientSARSA(env, 128, 0.005, 0.2)
agent.train(n_episodes=300)
```

I tried different rewards, Dropout Layers, Gradient clipping, different learning rates, different size of layers, literally everything. But the agent does not learn to solve the mountain car environment, especially due to catastrophic forgetting. I also tried other environments like Cartpole, but catastrophic forgetting is an issue there aswell. Any ideas what else I could try or maybe something is wrong in the code?